# Minecraft constantly crashes on Chromebook

Tags: java, games, minecraft

So i just downloaded minecraft from Chromebook and my game keeps crashing when i try to launch it, please help me try to fix it here is what it said

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// I bet Cylons wouldn't have this problem.

Time: 9/3/16 3:14 PM
Description: Initializing game

java.lang.RuntimeException: glCheckFramebufferStatus returned unknown status:0
    at bom.b(SourceFile:151)
    at bom.a(SourceFile:57)
    at bom.(SourceFile:42)
    at bcx.an(SourceFile:439)
    at bcx.a(SourceFile:381)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Client thread
Stacktrace:
    at bom.b(SourceFile:151)
    at bom.a(SourceFile:57)
    at bom.(SourceFile:42)
    at bcx.an(SourceFile:439)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at bcx.a(SourceFile:381)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.10
    Operating System: Linux (amd64) version 3.10.18
    Java Version: 1.6.0_39, Sun Microsystems Inc.
    Java VM Version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Sun Microsystems Inc.
    Memory: 61986072 bytes (59 MB) / 163905536 bytes (156 MB) up to 1060372480 bytes (1011 MB)
    JVM Flags: 5 total; -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.10
    LWJGL: 2.9.4
    OpenGL: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Bay Trail  GL version 1.4 (3.0 Mesa 10.1.3), Intel Open Source Technology Center
    GL Caps: Using GL 1.3 multitexturing.
Using GL 1.3 texture combiners.
Using framebuffer objects because EXT_framebuffer_object is supported.
Shaders are not available because OpenGL 2.1 is not supported, ARB_shader_objects is not supported, ARB_vertex_shader is not supported, and ARB_fragment_shader is not supported.
VBOs are not available because 
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU: 4x Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU N2930 @ 1.83GHz
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new profile with no modifications before launching the game from the launcher. Also, you are using Java 1.6, you might try Java 1.8 instead. Oracle's Java is the most reliable with Minecraft.

Download Oracle's 1.8 Java from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

You will want the Linux x64 (or x86, if you have a 32 bit system) tar.gz package.

1. Download the package
2. Extract it using `tar -xvf <packagename>.tar.gz`
3. Move the package to the correct place using `sudo mv <foldername> /usr/local/share`
4. Change the profile settings in Minecraft to use the `java` executable in the 's bin folder (ie `/usr/local/share/<foldername>/bin/java`. (change the profile settings, and change the java executable path to this)
5. Run minecraft with Oracle's Java 1.8

Comment: but i can't find java 1.8 on the ubuntu software centet

Comment: there's just 1.6 and 1.7

Comment: @KevinPham I updated the answer with instructions.

Comment: what is the folder name?????

Comment: Depends on which version you downloaded. Look at the file you downloaded, cut off the ".tar.gz" from the end, that is the <packagename> and <foldername>.